# initializing nested data structure with dictionary of dictionary of list of lists

Tags: python

I have to read data from a text file and insert it into a structure that is like a dictionary of dictionary with two keys in the inner dictionary "baseline" and "current". The value for "baseline" is a list of lists (actually the inner list always holds two elements) and for "current" is a list. Is there a way to initialize such a structure by default or is it better to use a class?
I am just showing the example below on how I explicitly constructed an object "m" but I wanted to know the best way to do such initializations.

```
 m = {0:{"baseline":[["hi","hello"],["bye","fellow"]], "current":["why","you"]},
      1:{"baseline":[["frank","bow"],["you","mad"]], "current":["silly","boy"]}
}
```

Comment: could you use JSON for your data? JSON seems very applicable

Comment: But I want to access this data and parse it later and even modify/append it.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the structure of the text file that you read. I normally would not initialize the data structure in code but would build it as I read and parse the source file.

Is that file's structure already defined?  Or are you expected to define it?

Is the data sourced from a database, parsed from a text, or does somebody have to key it into a structured format?

JSON would be the normal approach for storing the files, but it is tedious and error-prone to key data into this format.

YAML is better for keying data in if you take the few minutes to orient yourself to reading and writing its structure correctly.

Coming up with your own format is not a good idea unless you have complete control over who will be using it.

If you install `pyyaml`, you can run the following sample code:

```
import json
import yaml

m = {0:{"baseline":[["hi","hello"],["bye","fellow"]], "current":["why","you"]},
      1:{"baseline":[["frank","bow"],["you","mad"]], "current":["silly","boy"]}
}

print("=== YAML START ===")
print(yaml.dump(m))
print("=== YAML END ===")

print("\n\n")

print("=== JSON START ===")
print(json.dumps(m, indent=2))
print("=== JSON END ===")
```

Output samples follow so you can choose which format better fits your workflow.

Once you decide on a format, the idea would be that your code would use either the JSON or YAML library's native loading and parsing method to load the data from your file, and you will have all of it within your program in the structure you described.  This is intended to make it easier for you to input and then edit the raw data.

```
=== YAML START ===
0:
  baseline:
  - - hi
    - hello
  - - bye
    - fellow
  current:
  - why
  - you
1:
  baseline:
  - - frank
    - bow
  - - you
    - mad
  current:
  - silly
  - boy

=== YAML END ===
```

```
=== JSON START ===
{
  "0": {
    "baseline": [
      [
        "hi",
        "hello"
      ],
      [
        "bye",
        "fellow"
      ]
    ],
    "current": [
      "why",
      "you"
    ]
  },
  "1": {
    "baseline": [
      [
        "frank",
        "bow"
      ],
      [
        "you",
        "mad"
      ]
    ],
    "current": [
      "silly",
      "boy"
    ]
  }
}
=== JSON END ===
```

Comment: I am expected to make this structure myself it is not there in written file. I also want to access this structure again to modify

Comment: @vkaul11 Please have a look at the example output to choose which you prefer to maintain.  If you do not like either, then you will need to devise your own format and write your own parser.  With either of these formats you can read modified results with the built-in JSON or YAML parser so long as you maintain valid structure while editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use a library, you can relatively easy initialize, load, access, modify and store the values via pandas. If you print the dataframe (df) you also get a good overview of your data.

**Example below:**

```
import pandas as pd

m = {0:{"baseline":[["hi","hello"],["bye","fellow"]], "current":["why","you"]},
      1:{"baseline":[["frank","bow"],["you","mad"]], "current":["silly","boy"]}}

# load dictionary into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(m, orient='index')

# change a value
df.loc[1, "current"] = ["billy" if y == "silly" else y for y in df.loc[1, "current"]]

# output into dictionary again
print(df.to_dict(orient='index'))
```

**out:**

```
{0: {'baseline': [['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'fellow']], 'current': ['why', 'you']}, 
1: {'baseline': [['frank', 'bow'], ['you', 'mad']], 'current': ['billy', 'boy']}}
```

**Initialization**

If you want to initialize the dataframe you can use something like this:

```
l_0 = [[["hi","hello"],["bye","fellow"]], ["why","you"]]
l_1 = [[["frank","bow"],["you","mad"]], ["silly","boy"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["baseline", "current"], data = [l_0, l_1])
```

Comment: What I want to do is ingest information from a file (only picking up some columns) into such a structure

Comment: can u provide an example? Do you read the data into a table format, like in pandas? if that is the case it is rather easy to provide the dataframe with the data. But you should then change your question with like: input data -> expected output see [mre]